# django storing value in model

Tags: python, django

how i store value in `data` field in `logs model` using `id_` from `information model`

```
# Create your models here.
class information(models.Model):
    id_=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    modelno=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id_

class logs(models.Model):
    info=models.ForeignKey(information, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

i tried this but fails

```
 try:
 obj=information.objects.get(id_=21)   #21 is example id
 obj.logs.create(data=5000)   #need to store 5000
 except:
 print("exception")             #always throwing exception not saving
```

Comment: What isn't working? Why are `id_` and `modelno` a `CharField` too?..

Comment: it may contain alpha numeric so i select CharField

Comment: i tried  using "try" it throws exception, im not sure about this `obj.logs.create(data=5000)` think this is wrong

Comment: Doing `except:` isn't helpful, it hides the problem. What is the full traceback when you remove the try except block?

Comment: @Alasdair after removing "try" its not giving any error/traceback detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
obj.logs_set.create(data=5000)
```

Or you shoud define **related_name** for the field **info** like,

```
info=models.ForeignKey(information, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="logs")
```

then you can use like

```
obj.logs.create(data=5000)
```